# popup window needs to stay up if mouse leaves via another panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a mouse over popup window **(DIV B)** over one of my components **(DIV A)**. It is basically a filter popup that comes up when a user hovers over a table item.

Here is a diagram which shows mouse movements :

[image: diagram mouse movements]

1. Mouse enters DIV A, DIV B pops up.
2. Mouse leaves DIV A, DIV B disappears.
3. Mouse leaves DIV A into DIV B, but DIV B still remains open
4. Mouse leaves DIV B, DIV B disappears.

I am using a jQuery mouseover for step **(1)** which works fine. I am using a jQuery mouseLeave for step **(2)** which works fine too.

My problem is step **(3)**. I am trying to listen on the mouse leaving **DIV A**, but if it leaves **DIV A** via **DIV B** then do NOT remove the **DIV B**. I want to somehow say if mouseLeaves, but mouse is over **DIV B** then don't hide it. Some kind of mouseOver event? a mouseMotion listener?

This is the code i so far have :

```
$(this.filterFlag).mouseover(function(){
    self.view.appendChild(self.pop.getView());
});
$(this.filterFlag).mouseleave(function(){
    self.view.removeChild(self.pop.getView());

    //but if mouse leaves into the popup, don't hide pop up.
});
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: put div A and B in a global div. It will fit its content if you don't specify any size. Just bind the mouseleave to the container to make the div B disapear and the mouseenter to div A to make div B apear. If Div B is hidden, div A = div content. If div B is visible, div content = divA + div B. That's what you are looking for.

Comment: no can't do that. In the diagram DIVA and DIVB are exactly aligned, but in reality DIVB spills out to the right (ie is wider), so they can't both fit into a DIV exactly

Comment: So, give them a classname that isn't binded with style, but only used for selection. Something like `<div id="divA" class="myClass ..."/> some stuff <div id=divB" class="myClass ..."/>` and in the js `$("#divA").mouseenter(function(){$("#divB").show();});`  `$(".myClass").mouseleave(function(){ $("#divB").hide();});` You see what I mean.

Comment: check this out: [Click ME](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/exploring-web-typography/index.html). It is all in CSS3 though but it might help you with some stuff

Comment: @686 ha ha that's awesome. But I think i will go with Tamils answer

Comment: @686: Nice Link. I choosed bad :-). One more thing, your name & OP's reputation looked same & I thought both are same person :W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` events for `B` & when those events occurs trigger `A`'s corresponding events. This is very inefficient, but works.

Also keep in mind that, If `self.pop.getView()` returns same element for each call, you will have to unbind & rebind the events.

```
$(this.filterFlag).mouseover(function(){
    var that = this;
    var c = self.pop.getView();
    self.view.appendChild(c);
    $(c).mouseenter(function() {
      $(that).mouseenter();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
      $(that).mouseleave();
    });
});
$(this.filterFlag).mouseleave(function(){
    self.view.removeChild(self.pop.getView());

    //but if mouse leaves into the popup, don't hide pop up.
});
```

Here is a sample **[fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/C6bkP/)**

---

CSS solution will be more efficient.

### HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div id='A'></div>
  <div id='B'></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#B { display: none;}
.parent:HOVER #B { display: block;}
```